# Subscript is out of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm having troubles with my code. I'm trying to get data posted from one worksheet to another. I defined two worksheets in my code, and put my sheet range in an array. Then I wanted to create a loop that would post the data from column E from the business sheet in my engagment sheet, if column D has a number of 3 or higher. However, when I run it it says

```
Subscript is out if range
```

My code is as followed

```
Sub Simple_if2()
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shE As Worksheet, lastRB As Long, lastRE As Long
 Dim score As Integer, i As Long, k As Long, arrB  As Variant

'Worksheet definitions
 Set shB = Worksheets("Business")
 Set shE = Worksheets("Engagement Plan (High Priority)")
 
 lastRB = shB.Range("D" & shB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRE = shB.Range("E" & shB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 arrB = shB.Range("D6:E6" & lastRB & lastRE).Value  'put the shB sheet range in an array
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrB))      'redim arrE at maximum possible dimension

 
 'Loop for Business worksheet
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrB)
    If arrB(2, i) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrB(1, i) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
    End If
 Next i
 
 
 ReDim Preserve arrE(k + 1)  'redim the array to keep only the filled elements

 'drop the array content at once:
 shE.Range("B3").Resize(UBound(arrE) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrE)
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: `shB.Range("D6:E6" & lastRB & lastRE)` is probably the wrong range... `Debug.Print "D6:E6" & lastRB & lastRE` and see what the result is.

Comment: I think you have your refs backwards should be `arrB(i, 2)` and `arrB(i, 1)`

Comment: @BigBen - It gives me an error saying type mismatch. How would a define my ´arrB´ with the ´Debug.Print´?

Comment: No, just `Debug.Print "D6:E6" & lastRB & lastRE`. The result is going to be something like `D6:E65555` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @ScottCraner you're correct, I had them backwards. However, it didn't not seem to help my issue with defining the range for my array

Comment: You probably want `"D6:E" & lastRB`. It doesn't make sense to try to use the last row from two columns.

Comment: @BigBen it worked! `arrB=shB.Range("D6:E" & lastRB).value` worked. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

1. Swap the `2` and `i` and `3` and `i`: `arrB(i, 1)` and `arrB(i, 2)`
2. Correct the reference for the range before reading its `.Value` into an array: `shB.Range("D6:E" & lastRE).Value`

```
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shE As Worksheet, lastRB As Long, lastRE As Long
 Dim score As Integer, i As Long, k As Long, arrB  As Variant

'Worksheet definitions
 Set shB = Worksheets("Business")
 Set shE = Worksheets("Engagement Plan (High Priority)")

 lastRB = shB.Range("D" & shB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastRE = shB.Range("E" & shB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 arrB = shB.Range("D6:E" & lastRE).Value 'put the shB sheet range in an array
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrB))      'redim arrE at maximum possible dimension


 'Loop for Business worksheet
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrB)
    If arrB(i, 1) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrB(i, 2) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
    End If
 Next i


 ReDim Preserve arrE(k + 1)  'redim the array to keep only the filled elements

 'drop the array content at once:
 shE.Range("B3").Resize(UBound(arrE) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrE)
End Sub
```